# Python3 Interpreter for Komodo IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter, komodo-ide

I'm using Komodo IDE 11 and I want to program in Python 3.8.1. I already set a interpreter in Preferences > Languages > Python3, but it always give me the same error.

```
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 11.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/bin/py3_dbgp", line 105, in <module>
    import dbgp.client
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 11.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/python3lib/dbgp/client.py", line 1975
    def interaction(self, frame, tb = None, async = 0):
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm doing this in Mac OS X El Capitan, but also i need to do it in Windows 10 and Debian.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: async is a reserved word from python 3.7 so it should not be used as a parameter of a function, class, etc. causing you the error you point out. It seems that dbgp has not been updated, I recommend updating it since perhaps in recent versions it has been fixed, on the other hand I recommend you to report the bug.

Comment: Thank you so much. I update Komodo IDE and now it works.